# Jquery compare 4000 values with 4000 checkbox values and check matches

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, checkbox

I've inherited some shoddy code. The main problem I'm having is that the browser (I'm using Chrome) may have to iterate through potentially thousands of values (it's unlikely but it could happen), compare these values to potentially thousands of checkbox values and check the ones that match (I know this is poor design). I've created a fiddle to illustrate with about 4000 values and checkboxes: http://jsfiddle.net/zargarf/LG83j/3/

```
function checkAppropriateCheckBoxes(divId, inputName) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
        var val = $('#' + divId).prop('value');
    var boxes = $("input[name='" + inputName + "']");
        if (val != '') {
            var boxes=$("input[name='" + inputName + "']");
                $.each(val.split(",").slice(0, -1),
                    function(index, item) {
                        boxes.each(function() {

                            if ($(this).prop("value") == $.trim(item)) {
                                $(this).prop("checked", true);
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });

        }
    alert((new Date().getTime() - start));
    }

  $('.selectAll').click(function(){
       $('#courses input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
        return false;
    });
   $('.selectNone').click(function(){

       $('#courses input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
   });

checkAppropriateCheckBoxes('sessionCourse', 'course');
```

The html structure is similar to below:

```
<p>
<input id="sessionCourse" type="hidden" value="2SFASSA08R/131401,6CDCNHA01R/131501,loads more comma separated values"/>
</p>
<div id="courses">
<ul id="course" name="course" class="filters_value_list">
<li><input type="checkbox" name="course" id="cbcol-6EDEIPB01R/121401" value="6EDEIPB01R/121401"><label for="cbcol-6EDEIPB01R/121401" class="cognosFilterLabel">(AWE) BTEC L3 Diploma in Electrical/Electronic Engineering (6EDEIPB01R/121401)</label></li>

repeated for a tonne of lines
</ul>
</div>
```

Basically, it's taking over 20 seconds for the page to render and for the appropriate checkboxes to be checked. Basically when used in the proper application it is freezing an ajax waiting image while it's processing (not shown in the fiddle).

Do any of you have any ideas how to speed it up the iteration and to stop the browser from stopping a rotating image from spinning?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think any solution here will be a band-aid. You really need to add some pagination, or filtering on that ridiculously sized list.

Comment: the time can be brought down to ~3 seconds by replacing `boxes.each` with  `$("input[name='" + inputName + "'][value='" + $.trim(item) + "']").prop("checked", true);`. jQuery selector is pretty fast

Comment: I agree Rory, but unfortunately I don't have the luxury of a rewrite, and this is only a fraction of the poor design!

Comment: Thanks Ejay for the quick response - that worked much better! If you put the comment under the answer, I'll mark it.